Deploy .NET Desktop Runtime using MDM Configuration Service Provider
I'm pushing my app's MSI via MDM on wide range of devices. Now I need to upgrade to .NET 8.0. To this end I need to preinstall .NET Runtime on the target PCs. How can I do it using MDM CSP?
The problem for me is that .NET Runtime installer is an EXE-file but I can't find a way to install EXE using MDM.
